# pagination Chrome web scraper

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pagination, web-scraping

I have the data and it works perfectly. But I can't get the scraper to navigate to the next page. Does anyone know where I should put the "next page" link?
Here's the graph/map [enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/48ytk6kq9/)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two {[1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screenscraper/pfegffhjcgkneoemnlniggnhkfioidjg) & [2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scraper/mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd)} Chrome scraper plugins avail. *None of them* manages pagination. See their use cases: [1 (see comments there too)](https://webscraping.pro/how-to-scrape-yellow-pages-with-screenscraper-chrome-extension/) and [2](https://webscraping.pro/scraper-google-chrome-extension-review/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using the Chrome Extension "Web Scraper" which allows pagination. I can scrape the data perfectly, but cannot see where to put the "next page" link to loop through. http://postimg.org/image/4g6drz61n/  http://postimg.org/image/k60d0rs2f/